# How can I decompress multiple dat.gz files to csv?

Tags: python-3.x

I have multiple dat.gz files from one location (drive) to another host. How should I convert dat.gz files to csv and transfer?

Comment: Since this is tagged with python-3.x I presume that you are wanting to do this with Python code rather than the terminal shell?  Also, is the contents of the dat.gz file already a csv file just compressed?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ gunzip -v *.dat.gz
$ for FILE in *.dat
do
    mv ${FILE} `basename ${FILE} .dat`.csv
done
```

To transfer from one directory (drive) to another,
consider using [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/):

```
$ rsync -av src_dir/*.csv dest_dir/
```